# Plotting barplots using three categorical variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame is similar to this

```
df<-read.table (text=" Gender   Fruit   Food
Male    Pear    Yes
Female  Pear    Yes
Male    Grape   Yes
Female  Apple   No
Male    Grape   No
Male    Pear    No
Male    Guba    Yes
Male    Grape   No
Female  Apple   No
Female  Pear    Yes
Female  Apple   Yes
Male    Guba    No
Female  Guba    No
Male    Pear    Yes
Male    Apple   Yes
Male    Pear    No
Female  Pear    Yes
Male    Guba    No

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get a barplot like this along with a table under this plot to show numbers:

[image]

In plot G, A, G, P should read Grape, Apple, Guba and Pear

It would be good if we could have a table under this plot to see the values. This has been done in Excel simply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `ggplot` you need to map each of your variables of interest to an aesthetic or a facet. So something like that could work:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Fruit, fill=Food),
           position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~Gender)
```

[image: barplot with counts along 3 variables]

To add the table, you can simply compute it separately, then convert it to a graph element.

```
p_grph <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Fruit, fill=Food),
           position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~Gender)

p_table <- df %>%
  group_by(Gender, Fruit, Food) %>%
  summarize(count=n()) %>%
  gridExtra::tableGrob()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p_grph, p_table)
```

[image: plot on top and table below]

Comment: As Duck illustrated, you can generate the table separately with `group_by` and `summarize`, and attach it with the plot with `patchwork` (or include them both  in an Rmarkdown document). I'm editing my answer with a `gridExtra` illustration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Fruit,y=N,fill=Fruit))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  facet_wrap(Gender~Food,scales = 'free',nrow = 1)+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to add a table, you can use `patchwork`:

```
library(patchwork)
#Data for table
Tab <- df %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(N=n()) 
#Code
G1 <- df %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Fruit,y=N,fill=Fruit))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  facet_wrap(Gender~Food,scales = 'free',nrow = 1)+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
#Compose
G1+gridExtra::tableGrob(Tab)
```

Output:

[image]

If you want the table below, you can change `+` by `/`.

Comment: @user330 Yes, I will add now!

Comment: @user330 I have added an update, hoping that helps!

Comment: Thank you- I am sorry, but when I run your codes on large sample size, barplot looks the same. and the table provided does not help as there is no evidence of the frequency distribution of variables. I can get easily using SPSS and Excel.

Comment: @user330 Yeah, with large data you should be careful of how to arrange the data, here the sample is small.